# Is it possible to display hidden input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Is it possible to display `input type ="hidden"` value?

I need input type hidden because its my requirement and I want to make my generic and apply loop.

I know its a simple question. And I have been searching a lot. I searched and obviously tried also using `css`, `jquery` and `javascript` to `visible` but I m not getting any solution to it.

The code I tried is:
`input type="hidden" id="old1"`

and I applied `.hide()` and `.show()` function in `jquery`

Then I tried using in javascript as below:
`document.getElementById("Old1").style.visibility = "visible";`

OR

`document.getElementById("Old1").style.display = "block";`

But none of the solution is helping me.

Comment: you can change attribute of hidden value

Comment: $("#Old1").attr("type",text);

Comment: It says text is not defined.

Comment: write in double quotes

Comment: He means `$("#Old1").attr("type","text");`

Comment: thanks @jacob-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Perfect!!
But then it has become input type ="text" which I don't want

But I can hide it using css

Comment: Thank u so much to both of you!! :)

Comment: Is there another way to do the same?
I mean instead of making it input type ="text"

Answer (score 0):

```js
var value = $('#country').val();

alert(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="country" type="hidden" name="country" value="Norway">
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ivan Karaman
I m getting its value.
But I want to placed input type="hidden" on UI which I was not getting .
But you people saved my time.

```js
var value = $('#country').val();

alert(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="country" type="hidden" name="country" value="Norway">
```

Comment: input has id for getting value, for what u need ui ?